# Asp.NET Content Place Holder Error occurs in server

Tags: asp.net

I do not know why I am experiencing this error. Actually content place holders are placed in the right positions. Before I was able to view it on the webserver but now I received this error but the thing is the web is running smoothly on my local machine without any errors.

Here's my sitemaster code.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

   <head>
    <title>Manila Teachers'</title>


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/wrench84watermark.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var GB_ROOT_DIR = "./assets/greybox/";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ie6blocker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/greybox/gb_styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/StyleSheet.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
v\:* { behavior:url(#default#VML); }
</style> 
<style type="text/css">
iframe {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
a {
    outline: none;
 }
a img {
    border:none;
 }
    .style1
    {
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xmlFiles/feedbacks.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FEEDBACK");
i=0;

function displayFeedback()
{
numero=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("NUMBER") [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
description=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DESCRIPTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
author=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
profile=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("PROFILE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="<center><img src='images/headerfeed.jpg'></center>"+"<br />Feedback#" + numero+ "<br /><br/><b>Message:</b> " + "<br/><br/>"+description + "<br /><br/><b>Name:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; " + "<u>"+author +"</u>"+ "<br /><b>Profile:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; "+"<u>"+ profile+ "</u>";
document.getElementById("showFB").innerHTML=txt;
}
function next()
{
if (i<x.length-1)
  {
  i++;
  displayFeedback();
  }
}

function previous()
{
if (i>0)
  {
  i--;
  displayFeedback();
  }
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="displayFeedback()" >


<div id="top"></div>


<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
<img src="images/mt2.jpg" alt="banner" width = "100%" height= "100%" />
</div>

<div id="top-menu" class="funtext">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
<li><a href ="About.aspx">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href = "">Products</a></li>
<li> <a href ="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>


<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" runat="server">
<div id="mainContent"></div>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<div class="horizontalRule"></div>
        <div id="footer-menu">
        <a href="Default.aspx" class="myLink">Home</a>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <a href="About.aspx" class="myLink">About Us</a>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;<a  class="myLink" href="Careers.aspx">Careers</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="myLink" href="news.aspx" >News</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="myLink" href="Privacy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="myLink" href="Terms.aspx">Terms of Use</a>
        </div>     

<hr style ="color:#CCCCCC;" />     



<div id="footer">

@ 2012  All Rights Reserved.
   <br /><br />
 This website is best viewed on Internet Explorer 7 or above, Mozilla Firefox and Safari Browsers.

</div> 

  <div class="clear"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
>   was thrown.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 110: Line 111: Line 112: Line 113: Line
>   114:
>
> Source File: /Site.master    Line: 112
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

My web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
              <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
              <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                  <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
                  <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                  <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                  <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
              </sectionGroup>
          </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup> 
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
      <httpRuntime enableHeaderChecking="true" />
         <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Oops.aspx">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="Oops.aspx" />
         </customErrors>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages>

      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="GET" path="FtbWebResource.axd" type="FreeTextBoxControls.AssemblyResourceHandler, FreeTextBox" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="googlemaps.subgurim.net" value="AIzaSyAcp1BPyW4rV8NTn9iqgzhQLOE2eaE_sVI" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you post the server side code?  the error is telling you the error occurred on line 112, not the html...  I also notice the webserver is running .net 4.0 and your site is compiled as 3.5.  I'm not sure if that's even an issue, but just throwing it out there.

Comment: here is the code that produces the error:Line 110:
Line 111:
Line 112:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" runat="server">
Line 113:<div id="mainContent"></div>
Line 114:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

Comment: Try this way:

    `<div id="mainContent">
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" runat="server">
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On of the bugs that I see is that you include the jQuery two times.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Keep only one, the last one.

Comment: i believe it is not the solution.

Comment: @Dhenn Probably yes but is a start - is an obvious bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your web.conifg file you are doing mistake in your master page syntax. Use the following code to get rid. i have exclude your links etc becasue i dont have those file.
use this code to get rid from this problem

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage2.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div id="top"></div> 


<div id="wrapper"> 

<div id="header"> 
<img src="images/mt2.jpg" alt="banner" width = "100%" height= "100%" /> 
</div> 

<div id="top-menu" class="funtext"> 
<ul id="menu"> 
<li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href ="About.aspx">About Us</a></li> 
<li><a href = "">Products</a></li> 
<li> <a href ="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a> </li> 
</ul> 
</div> 


<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content" runat="server"> 
<div id="mainContent"></div> 
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
<div class="horizontalRule"></div> 
        <div id="footer-menu"> 
        <a href="Default.aspx" class="myLink">Home</a> 
        &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        <a href="About.aspx" class="myLink">About Us</a> 
            &nbsp; &nbsp;<a  class="myLink" href="Careers.aspx">Careers</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="myLink" href="news.aspx" >News</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="myLink" href="Privacy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;<a class="myLink" href="Terms.aspx">Terms of Use</a> 
        </div>      

<hr style ="color:#CCCCCC;" />      



<div id="footer"> 

@ 2012  All Rights Reserved. 
   <br /><br /> 
 This website is best viewed on Internet Explorer 7 or above, Mozilla Firefox and Safari Browsers. 

</div>  

  <div class="clear"></div>  
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it won't work.. i want my menus footer and other elements to be static, and i place the content in a content place holder.. It was working on my localmachine but does not on the web server

Comment: Send me the whole project on my id kmrizwan.shahid@gmail.com let me check why you are getting error